# Mysql - Error code 1054 Unknown cloumn 'players.p_name' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql-error-1054

Hello,

first of all I want you to show my table I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `channels` (
`channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`channel_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `gamepoints` (
 `gp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `gamble` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `roulette` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `blackjack` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `slots` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`gp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `player_channel` (
`pc_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`players_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pc_id`),
 KEY `players_id_idx` (`players_id`),
KEY `channel_id_idx` (`channel_id`),
CONSTRAINT `channel_id` FOREIGN KEY (`channel_id`) REFERENCES `channels` (`channel_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `players_id` FOREIGN KEY (`players_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`players_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `players` (
 `players_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `p_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `p_right` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `gp_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`players_id`),
KEY `gp_id_idx` (`gp_id`),
CONSTRAINT `gp_id` FOREIGN KEY (`gp_id`) REFERENCES `gamepoints` (`gp_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I wanted to this query:

```
UPDATE gamepoints SET gamble = 1 
WHERE gamepoints.gp_id = players.gp_id
AND players.p_name = "test"
AND player_channel.players_id = players.players_id
AND player_channel.channel_id = channels.channel_id
AND channels.channel_name = "test";
```

But when I do this i get this Error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'players.p_name' in 'where clause'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, i tryed also after set to add from with all tables, but this works also not.

I would be really happy if someone can help me :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted the table names of all but `gamepoints`.  I would recommend that you use explicit join update syntax, which makes it harder to have this sort of error:

```
UPDATE gamepoints t1
INNER JOIN players t2
    ON t1.gp_id = t2.gp_id
INNER JOIN player_channel t3
    ON t3.players_id = t2.players_id
INNER JOIN channels t4
    ON t4.channel_id = t3.channel_id
SET t1.gamble = 1
WHERE t2.p_name = 'test' AND
      t4.channel_name = 'test';
```

If you wanted to salvage your current query, then it would start off looking something like this:

```
UPDATE gamepoints, players, player_channel, channels
SET gamble = 1
WHERE    -- a very large number of conditions
```

One reason implicit joins are frowned upon is that they mix normal restrictions on the result set with join conditions, all in the same `WHERE` clause.  This doesn't happen with the query as I wrote it using explicit joins.